# MySQL: Need to select a list of unique street names from a table of addresses

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains, amongst other things, a field specifying the street address of some places. I'm trying to figure out a way to return a subset of JUST the street NAMES from that table when they match a given search term.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT `street` FROM `addresses` 
WHERE (`street` LIKE '%searchTerm%')
GROUP BY `street` 
ORDER BY LOCATE('searchTerm',`street`) 
LIMIT 10;
```

Which does okay, except, of course, that it has the unwanted side effect of returning the whole street address including the house #, where ALL I want is the name of the street itself. I'm at a loss, however, as to how I can strip off any leading numbers, dashes or #-signs and collect JUST the street names from the query?

Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck just managing the results in code (PHP) after retrieving the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what kind of data you have. If the street name contains only one word throughout the database then you can take only that word. But what if it is multiple word? Anyway, mysql should not be used for this part of the problem as any function call or data manipulation  would have extra overhead on query time. You can separately index street names and select them. Better to go for elastic search.

Comment: The data is a single varchar field with elements generally of the form: "[[###-]####] Some Words Here [Street|Road|Crescent|Lane|Parkway|etc]"
i.e. typical street addresses. Obviously street names can be multiple words, the obvious characteristic is that the first part contains only numbers, and potentially a number sign, and/or a dash/hyphen followed by a space...

Comment: So how much do you want to return? This will give you whatever word is between the first and second space `(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(street, ' ', 2), ' ', -1))`

Comment: If you consider valid addresses such as `123 45th Street` and `123A Bravo Road`  you'll realize it's hard to do this with text processing as crude as that you get in an SQL dialect. You may want to use a programming language for this. To do it well, you'll need a catalog of the existing street names.

Comment: @miknik -- really, everything after the first space would probably work >98% of the time.

Comment: @O.Jones -- the only three "numbered" streets in the database are actually called "First Street", "Second Street" and "Third Street", so I had considered that, but wasn't concerned about it...

Comment: OK. When I worked on this sort of problem, a long time ago, I had data from everywhere in USA. Salt Lake City's addresses are a nightmare `123 W 4th St. S` is a typical one. A limited dataset helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after listening to the comments / advice above, and given the particulars of my specific use-case (where I can generally just assume that anything before the first space in the string is disposable information) I ended up with the following query, which actually works quite well:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(`street`,LOCATE(' ',`street`)+1,LENGTH(`street`)) AS `streetSearch`
FROM `addresses`
WHERE `street` LIKE ('%searchTerm%')
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`street`,LOCATE(' ',`street`)+1,LENGTH(`street`))
ORDER BY LOCATE('searchTerm',`street`)
LIMIT 10;
```

While I realise that there's a ton of stuff being taken for granted, given the data in the table that I'm working with, this solution works >99% of the time (i.e. it hasn't produced any false-positives/negatives in testing thus far).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding you simply need to separate the whole street name by finding the nearest spaces of the pattern '%searchTerm%'.
It is feasible in MySQL, however I would recommend to do it in code. In a case you really need it at the level of database I would put it into the [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html).

This is the code which works in MySQL. (It is possible to use it in query after some modifications - however I would not recommend it :))

```
SET @STREET='tree';
SET @HAYSTACK='Some man lives at some street 15 in some town in some country';
SET @STREET_START=locate(@STREET, @HAYSTACK) ;
-- first space
SET @FULL_STREET_START=@STREET_START - (SELECT locate(' ', 
reverse(substring(@HAYSTACK,1, @STREET_START )))) + 1;
-- last space
SET @FULL_STREET_END=LENGTH(@STREET) + locate(' ', 
substring(@HAYSTACK,@STREET_START+LENGTH(@STREET))) + 1;
SELECT substring(@HAYSTACK, @FULL_STREET_START, @FULL_STREET_END);
-- result
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring(@HAYSTACK, @FULL_STREET_START, @FULL_STREET_END) |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  street                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```